# Possibility to join OVPN when user is not logged on

Tags: vpn, openvpn, sql-server

I am trying to achieve an automation for SQL server agent to store backups in a remote computer, but sql server agent has first to join OVPN.

I have tried all the methods described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/547396/arguments-to-connect-using-open-vpn-windows-client), but in my case user is not necessarily logged on to start a GUI. Is there a possibility to join to OVPN without GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Start OpenVPN without a GUI

You can install and run [**OpenVPN** as a Service](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/install.html) with the configurations setup for your needs but set its **Startup type** to be **manual** so it does not auto start on its own at boot up, etc.

- > **Command to ensure OpenVPN Service does not Auto-Start**
  >
  > ```
  > SC CONFIG "OpenVPN Service" START= manual
  > ```

You can then have your automation job execute a batch script or if needed trigger a scheduled task that has elevated permissions to start that service to establish the VPN tunnel without the GUI.

- > **Command to the Start OpenVPN Service**
  >
  > ```
  > NET START "OpenVPN Service"
  > ```

Once the SQL Agent backup job completes successfully and the VPN tunnel is no longer needed, you can then have it stop the service to disconnect from the VPN tunnel.

- > **Command to the Stop OpenVPN Service**
  >
  > ```
  > NET STOP /Y "OpenVPN Service"
  > ```

---

### Further Resources

- [SC (Service Control)](https://ss64.com/nt/sc.html)
- [NET (Service Start & Stop)](https://ss64.com/nt/net-service.html)
- [Run a batch file from a scheduled Job via SQL Server Agent](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9106/how-do-i-run-a-batch-file-from-a-scheduled-job-via-sql-server-agent)