# How to use OpenVPN Windows 2.5 Client from the command line?

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, vpn, openvpn

My company is going with OpenVPN and I just got the client (version 2.5.0.100) working on my Windows 10 machine but I would like to connect (including authenticate), check the connection status and disconnect--all from the command line.

I thought that Googling something like "openvpn windows client command line" would produce something but I haven't found it. I searched for something similar in the OpenVPN forum but didn't find anything in that ocean.

Previously, I used Cisco AnyConnect, where I could issue commands like these:

```
vpncli.exe connect
```

This would prompt me to enter my credentials and then connect to the host using my default profile.

```
vpncli.exe state
```

This would output the current connection state of the VPN connection (e.g. CONNECTED etc.)

```
vpncli.exe disconnect
```

This would disconnect the current connection, if there was one.

Is it not possible to do something simple like this with OpenVPN 2.5 for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

"C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe" --connect "myvpn.ovpn"

Other suggestions:
[Arguments to connect using Open Vpn windows client](https://superuser.com/questions/547396/arguments-to-connect-using-open-vpn-windows-client)

Comment: Thanks, Andy, but I can't find `openvpn-gui.exe` anywhere. I tried the args that you suggested with some of the `.exe`s that I did find--`openvpn32.exe`, `openvpn64.exe` and `ovpncli.exe`--but they didn't like it. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that openvpn client. This is the one most commonly used: https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/